# C Assembly convert 0xffffffff

Tags: assembly, byte, x86-64, cpu-registers

If there is a register, say %eax that is an integer type. If %eax is 0xffffffff, what would x be?

This is on a 64-bit machine.

Since 0xffffffff is 4 bytes, what could be a possible x type? an int or unsigned int or unsigned long, right? Also, could the value be -1 or would it be 2^32 -1? Are we treating it as signed or unsigned?

I'm just struggling to understand how to go about this.

Comment: If we know that the value is 8 bytes, then 0xffffffff is short for 0x00000000ffffffff, which is not -1. but the other.  Consider decimal, where 15 is short for 015 or 0015 or 00015.  On the other hand, if we know it is 4 bytes, then it could be -1 or the other depending on who is interpreting it.  Hex values don't tell us whether they are signed or unsigned, that's a matter of interpretation.  (But a value with a 0 sign bit is positive whether the data type is signed or unsigned.)

Comment: `%eax` refers to the lower 4 bytes of `%rax`.  In 0xffffffff, the `x` means hex.

Comment: `int32_t` and `uint32_t` both use all 2^32 bit-patterns for unique values, so you can't tell from the bit-pattern whether EAX holds an `int` or `unsigned`.  You can rule out `unsigned long` if this is x86-64 System V, because in that ABI it's a 64-bit type.  (On Windows `unsigned long` is 32-bit).

Comment: If you were talking about a C numeric literal rather than a bit-pattern in a register, `0xffffffff` in C source has type `unsigned int`; numeric literals have a type wide enough to represent their *value*.  Numbers in C source are values, not bit-patterns.  For `0xffffffff` to become `-1` in C, you'd have to implicitly or explicitly convert it to a 32-bit 2's complement type, like `int`, e.g. with `int x = 0xffffffff;` which invokes the implementation-defined behaviour for converting out-of-range values into signed integer types.  (For normal 2's complement systems, just keep the bit-pattern.)